# Select Nth previous sibling in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css-selectors

I'm trying to set up my jQuery selector but I'm not exactly sure how I need to write it.

I've got a unordered list that looks something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>something</li>
    <li>something</li>
    <li>something</li>
    <li>something</li>
    <li class="last">something</li>
</ul>
```

Now I know if I want to select the last child I can do that by using either "ul li.last" or "ul.li:last" but say if I wanted the second from last, or third, or 20th? Now would I do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You use [`eq`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/eq):

```
$('ul li').eq(X);
```

Where X is a 0-based index of which element you want. You could also use the [selector form](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/eq#index):

```
$('ul li:eq(X)');
```

And you could also achieve a similar result by using [`nth-child`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/nthChild#index):

```
$('ul li:nth-child(X)');
```

The documentation has this to say about the difference between `nth-child` and `eq`:

> While :eq(index) matches only a single element, this matches more than one: One for each parent with index. Multiple for each parent with even, odd, or equation. The specified index is one-indexed, in contrast to :eq() which starts at zero.

So by doing `$('ul li').eq(19);` you would get the single 20th matched element of the query (so if there is more than one list in the document this won't get you "all 19th children", while `$('ul li:nth-child(20)');` would get you the individual 20th matched list element of each `<ul>` in the document.

**EDIT**:

To do something like "second to last", the sane way to do it would be like:

```
var $ul = $('#mylist > li');
var $el = $ul.eq($ul.length-2);
```

But you should probably do a check to make sure length-2 is not less than 0.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want the 3rd from last?

```
var $ul = $("ul li");
$ul.find(":eq(" + Math.max(0, $ul.length - 3) + ")");
```

Quick explanation:  The length of $ul (which is a jQuery object) is how many li's are found. So you can use that along with the ":eq(n)" selector to get the li at the desired index.

I used Math.max in case the list was too short (less than 3 li's).

This will also work, but it's obviously not the best way:

```
var $ul = $("ul li:last").prev().prev();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alert($('ul li').eq(3).text());
```

That will alert the text of the third list item.

Answer (score 0):

For third and twentieth, you can do `ul li:eq(3)` and `ul li:eq(20)`.  For second to last, you might be able to do something with [`nth-child`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/nthChild)'s `equation` argument option, though I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery team added this feature in version 1.9

You can read about it at http://api.jquery.com/nth-last-child-selector/