# jQuery target previous divs with integer number

Tags: jquery

I have following setup:

```
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>//Need to target this
<div class="item"></div>//Need to target this
<div class="item"></div>//Need to target this
<div class="item"></div>//Need to target this
<div class="item"></div>//Need to target this
<div class="item start"></div>//starting point
<div class="item"></div>
```

From `start` class div, I need to target 5 divs previous to it. So that all previous 5 will get a new class (addClass) like below:

```
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item good"></div>
<div class="item good"></div>
<div class="item good"></div>
<div class="item good"></div>
<div class="item good"></div>
<div class="item start"></div>//starting point
<div class="item"></div>
```

I have following:

```
var num = 5; //integer number
$(".start").prevUntil(??).addClass('good'); //??
```

How would I use the integer number to do this?

To clarify it better, the `start` class is the starting point and I need to add the class `good` to 5 previous divs from this starting point.

Thanks

Comment: Corret me if I'm wrong. You want to add a class to all 5 divs, following the 1st one? So all those also having the class 'good'?

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022595/select-nth-previous-sibling-in-jquery?

Comment: To clarify it better, the `start` class is the starting point and I need to add the class `good` to 5 previous divs from this starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab all of them using [`prevAll`](https://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) and then take only the first five of those previous elements by using [`slice`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/).

```js
var num = 5;
$(".start").prevAll().slice(0, num).addClass('good');
```

```css
.item::after {
  content: "ITEM";
}
.item.start::after {
  content: "START";
}
.item.good::after {
  content: "GOOD";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item start"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/) to get the previous elements, and [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to reduce it to just the first 5.

```js
$('.start').prevAll('div').slice(0, 5).addClass('good');
```

```css
.item {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: solid black 1px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.item.good {
  background-color: blue;
}
.item.start {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item start"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following:

```
var startIndex = $('.start').index();
var endIndex = startIndex - 5;

for(var i = startIndex - 1; i >= endIndex; i--){
    $('.item').eq(i).addClass('good');
}
```

Updated to not add class 'good' the start index.

https://jsfiddle.net/n2723fmu/

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     
     $(".start").prevAll("div").slice(0,5).addClass("good");
     
 })
```

```css
.item::after {
  content: "ITEM";
}
.item.start::after {
  content: "START";
}
.item.good::after {
  content: "GOOD";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item start"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using jQuery's `prevUntil()` function, you may simply use `prev()` for about the number of times you want to. A quick example would look like this:

```
var el = $('.start');
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  el = el.prev();
  el.addClass('good');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dzyvxzp3/1/